# Best ways to delete a big amount of docs in scheduled cloud functions

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am working in an use case where **every 5 minutes**, a scheduled cloud function will be executed. This function, that runs with 2GB of memory and a timeout of 256 secs., will query against a collection, trying to search expired docs.

As the success of deleting documents is crucial, I am afraid of the **errors that can occur with a large number of documents**... I have read that **batched deletes** is the key to solve this problem in most of the cases, but, **if one of the deletions fails, a big amount of deletions will be ignored**.

Currently, I am doing this:

```
 await allSettled(
    querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
        ...

        // Create a batched write
        const batch = firestore.batch();

        // Delete the doc
        batch.delete(doc.ref);

        // Decrease doc owner counter
        batch.set(
          ...
        );

        return batch.commit();
      })
      .then(() => { ... })
      .catch(() => { ... });

 ............................

 exports.allSettled = function (promises) {
  let wrappedPromises = promises.map((p) =>
    Promise.resolve(p).then(
      (val) => ({ status: "fulfilled", value: val }),
      (err) => ({ status: "rejected", reason: err })
    )
  );

  return Promise.all(wrappedPromises);
};
```

As you can see, I am not batching the "general" docs deletions, instead I am mapping the list of documents and, for each doc, in a independent batched operation, I delete it and decrease a counter.

Which way for deleting big amounts of docs from a collection is recommended (in order to avoid out-of-memory errors, etc.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you think it is possible to get a list of documents for deletion in the first cloud function (run every N minutes on scheduler), then divide that list into M non overlapping chunks, and push M messages (a 'chunk' per message) into some PubSub topic. On the other side of the topic, there is another cloud function (with a big max instances number) which are triggered by a PubSub message. That cloud function can do the deletion by going through the incoming list of documents (similar to the code you provided). In that case those deletion may go more or less in parallel.

If something is not deleted - it will simply should be picked up by the next scheduled 'job'.

Do you think it can be useful in your context?